# Prove that there are infinitely many composite numbers so that $\phi (n)$ divides $n-1$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that there are infinitely many composite numbers so that $\phi (n)$ divides $n-1$, where $\phi (n)$ is Euler's function.
I really don't know how to solve this, so could someone give me a hint or something else?
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: what is $\;\varphi(p)\;$ for  *prime* $\;p\;$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly infinitely many prime numbers $p$ with $\phi(p)\mid (p-1)$, namely all prime numbers. We have $\phi(p)=p-1$.
For composite numbers however it is not known whether or not there is *any* such integer. 
In fact, this is called [Lehrer's totient problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer's_totient_problem). Lehmer conjectured in $1932$ that there are no composite numbers $n$ with $\phi(n)\mid (n-1)$.

Comment: The original problem was to prove that there are infinitely many composite numbers sto that n divides $3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$. I though if I prove the Lehrer's totient problem I could solve it easy.